# how to obtain blob type data for insertion in oracle?

Tags: oracle, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

hello friends I have a problem with the blob data type, I want to migrate some data from one bd to another bd however I have not been able to some tables that have blob type columns, what I have tried is to export a single record in the following way.

first I make a select of the record I want to export to my other bd

```
select TEMPLATE_DOCUMENT_ID,blob_file  from example_table where template_document_id = 32;
```

then I export the result to obtain the insert

[image]

I configure as follows

[image]

when I do this I get a script with the data of the record that I want to migrate

[image]

if I run this it gives me the following error

```
Error report -
ORA-01465: invalid hex number
```

Do you have any idea how I could get the correct data to make my insert?

NOTE: MIGRATION IS DONE FROM ONE ORACLE DATABASE TO ANOTHER ORACLE DATABASE.

Comment: That insert statement doesn't look right; the concatenation operator only applies to strings, according to the documentation. Recent versions of SQL Developer silently skip BLOB columns when exporting as insert statement; which version are you using? [This might be helpful though.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/05/exporting-multiple-blobs-with-oracle-sql-developer/)

Comment: @AlexPoole I have tried this way but it does not generate my file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the source database is Oracle. You did not mention what is the target database. In case it is Oracle as well I would suggest using the Oracle Data Pump tool (expdp/impdp). Doc is here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm

In case you need it, at least I use it quite often is the VIEW_AS_TABLE option of the tool as it allows me to export a subset of the data.